# How to match a short list (#1) to a larger list (#2), and get a list of length #1 with data from list #2

Tags: r

I am working on a project, in which I have two sets of data, one from 2019 and one from 2015. I created a subgroup of the 2019 data, and would like to match that against the 2015 data based on address.

I have tried using `sapply` and `lapply`, however I have not been able to get it to work, since the lists are different lengths.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `merge`?

```
df.2019 <- data.frame(year = rep(2019, 6), address = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"))
df.2015 <- data.frame(year = rep(2015, 6), address = c("a10", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a15", "a16"))
df <- merge(df.2019, df.2015, by = "address"); df
> df <- merge(df.2019, df.2015, by = "address"); df
  address year.x year.y
1      a2   2019   2015
2      a3   2019   2015
3      a4   2019   2015
```

Answer (score 0):

1. merge works best with dataframes, you mentioned you have lists. Check the structure of your data first using `str(dataframe)` If you have list, convert to dataframes, you can use something like this: `list_to_dataframe <- as.dataframe(list)`
2. Once you have dataframes, use the merge function. A worked example is below:

```
dataframe_2019 <- data.frame(address = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), year = 
rep("2019"))

dataframe_2015 <- data.frame(address = c("A", "X", "Z", "B", "C", "G", "D", 
"Y"), year = rep("2015"))


new_dataframe <- merge(dataframe_2015, dataframe_2019, by = "address")

new_dataframe
  address year.x year.y
1       A   2015   2019
2       B   2015   2019
3       C   2015   2019
4       D   2015   2019
```

Comment: You're right! My mistake, it's in library(data.table)

Comment: It's also available in data.table: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/merge

Comment: ahh..okay. I didn't know that but I doubt if it is any different than `base::merge`

Comment: Very similar. I forget what is in base, dplyr and data.table as I normally have them all loaded!